# How to create and set checkbox in DataTables

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a table that is loaded with an AJAX call and rendered with the DataTables extension for jQuery.  This is my code:

```
 $("#tblSelectedUserRoles").dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetAllRolesForUser")?' + "userId=" + $("#txtSelectedUserId").val(),
        bJQueryUI: true,
        sProcessing: "<img src='~/Images/spinner.gif' />",
        dom: 'T<"clear">rtip',
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "20%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "20%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            {
                "sWidth": "20%", sClass: "smallFonts", "sName": "UserRoleId", "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<input type='checkbox' onchange=defaultrole('" + row[0] + "'); >";
                }},
            { "sWidth": "20%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            {
                "sName": "UserRoleId", "sWidth": "20%", sClass: "smallFonts", "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<button class='gridButton' onclick=deleterole('" + row[0] + "');>Delete Role</button>";
                }}
        ]
    });
```

I'm trying to put a checkbox in the table.  The checkbox show up and when I click on any of them I invoke the function with the proper user_role_id without a problem.  My problem is the data is coming from this in the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllRolesForUser(string userId)
    {
        List<UserRoleModel> userroles = DataRepository.GetSelectedUserRoles(userId);
        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = userroles.Select(x => new String[] {
                x.UserRoleId,
                x.Role,
                x.RoleDesc,
                x.Default.ToString(),
                x.UarApproved.ToString()})
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the default and approved valued are Boolean and I have to convert them to a string to pass then in the aaData.  In any case, none of the checkboxes are set when at least one should be.  How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually set the `checked` status. If the value that should define the checked status is `UarApproved` and that value is a stringified boolean, always `'true'` or `'false'`, then do this :

```
{
    sWidth: "20%",
    sClass: "smallFonts",
    sName: "UserRoleId",
    mRender: function(data, type, row) {
      return '<input type="checkbox" checked="'+row[4]+'" onchange=defaultrole('+row[0]+');/>';
    }
},
```